# Does anyone know how to save data when a view is exited?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, nsuserdefaults

I have a UITableView and its a checklist. I can add new cells to the table and you can also delete them. I want to know how to save the tables data when someone leaves/exits a view! Is this possible?Thanks everyone: D

I am using this to save the data:: would this work?

```
 NSArray *sourceData = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] arrayForKey:@"funds"];


if (!sourceData)
{
    NSString * myFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"cells" ofType:@"plist"];
    sourceData = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:myFile];
}



self.cells = [NSMutableArray array];


for (NSDictionary *immutableCellDictionary in sourceData)
{
    [self.cells addObject:[NSMutableDictionary   
dictionaryWithDictionary:immutableCellDictionary]];
}
```

Comment: i already did accept it! thanks for the help tho :D

Comment: It seems to me that you are retrieving the data from the plist and adding them to `self.cell`... this would go in `viewDidLoad`. For saving, use `setObject:forKey:`

Comment: hmm alright, but will this save the data when the user leaves the view?? Becuase if they add a cell after the view loads, then wouldnt it not save the new cells?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It all depends on what you mean by exiting/leaving a view. One option is using [`viewWillDisappear:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/viewWillDisappear:)

> viewWillDisappear:
>
> Notifies the view controller that its view is about to be dismissed, covered, or otherwise hidden from view.
>
> Subclasses can override this method and use it to commit editing changes, resign the first responder status of the view, or perform other relevant tasks.

If this is not fine with your app, please give some more detail about when exactly you want to save the view data.

Comment: hey i updated my question can u take a look at it please? thanks